# How to tell whether your controller action was given parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to determine whether my controller action was called with parameters or not, without hardcoding which parameters can be added on.

So I want to distinguish between

```
/my_controller
```

and

```
/my_controller?q=1
```

I know that I could look inside the params hash, and check whether it ONLY contains :controller and :action keys. This seems ugly to me, is there a smarter way of doing this check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one direct solution:

```
request.env["QUERY_STRING"] # => "q=1"
```

Or with Ruby 1.9.2:

```
request.env.QUERY_STRING # => "q=1"
```

Answer (score 1):

For GET request you can use `request.query_parameters` method. There is also `request.request_parameters` for POST requests.

Results for `request.query_parameters.inspect` are:

- for '/my_controller' => '{}'
- for '/my_controller?q=1' => {"q"=>"1"}

Comment: I like this solution too, just found a use for it.